# Is a nonincreasing expectation of a function value sequence a supermartingale sequence?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \omega \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\omega \sim D$. Assume $(f(x_k, \omega_k))$ be a random sequence such that

$$
\mathbb{E}_{\omega^{k+1}} [f(x_{k+1}, \omega_{k+1})] \leq f(x_{k}, \omega_{k})
$$
where $f(x_{k}, \omega_{k})$ is just a realization at the $k$-th step.

**Question1**

Is $(f(x_k, \omega_k))$ a supermartingale sequence?

**Question2**

If so, assuming $f$ is bounded below, can we show that $(f(x_k, \omega_k))$ converges to some random variable with probability one using [Doob's martingale convergence theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems)?

Comment: What's $D$? Besides: isn't your assumption already the supermartingale condition? In that case you should only assume the measurability and integrability and you're done. For question 2: what do you want to prove? By Doob's theorem you have the required convergence. Perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: @finch: $D$ is some distribution which we know. I had not noticed that my assumption implies the supermartingale condition because I was trying to show that before. Now, I have that condition that holds so it is a supermartingale sequence. How can I show measurability. I know $f \in C^1$, does that imply  the measurability and integrability ?